# How can I return a html view from an ajax call in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.1

I am trying to render an html view via ajax call and in success callback i will add this html to DOM.But i am not getting any response in the success callback.

```php
public function create()
    {
        $format = new ProductFormat();
        //return response()->view('cms.formats.create_modal', compact('format'));
        return (String) view('cms.formats.create_modal', compact('format'));

    }
```

```js
$.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'GET',
                    type: 'html',
                    url: '{{ url("admin/formats/create") }}',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#format_modal').html(data);
                        $('#add_edit_format_modal').modal('show');

                    }
                }).error(function(e){
                    console.log(e);
                });
```

error callback is getting the html response but why not in success call back?

my response is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_edit_format_modal" tabIndex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">  <!--start modal content-->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    ×
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Product Format</h4>
            </div>
            <!--start modal body-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="add_format">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="format_title_en" class="col-md-3 control-label">Title (en)</label
>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="format_title_en" value="" name="format_title_en" class="form-control"
 type="text" required="required">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="format_title_fr" class="col-md-3 control-label">Title (fr)</label
>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="format_title_fr" value="" name="format_title_fr" class="form-control"
 type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="barcode" class="col-md-3 control-label">Barcode</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="barcode" value="" name="barcode" class="form-control" type="number"
>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="packaging_type" class="col-md-3 control-label">Packaging Type</label
>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="format_packaging_type" name="packaging_type"
>
                                <option value="">Other</option>
                                <option value="bottled">Bottled</option>
                                <option value="canned">Canned</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="amount_g" class="col-md-3 control-label">Size (g)</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="amount_g" value="" name="amount_g" class="form-control" type="number"
 onkeydown="validateNumberAllowDecimal(event, true)">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="amount_ml" class="col-md-3 control-label">Size (ml)</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="amount_ml" value="" name="amount_ml" class="form-control" type
="number" onkeydown="validateNumberAllowDecimal(event, true)">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="size_indicated_amount" class="col-md-3 control-label">Size Indicated
 Amount</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="size_indicated_amount" value="" name="size_indicated_amount" class
="form-control" type="number" onkeydown="validateNumberAllowDecimal(event, true)">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="size_indicated_unit" class="col-md-3 control-label">Size Indicated
 Unit</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="size_indicated_unit" value="" name="size_indicated_unit" class
="form-control" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="store_code" class="col-md-3 control-label">Store Code</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="store_code" value="" name="store_code" class="form-control" type
="number">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="price" class="col-md-3 control-label">Price</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="price" value="" name="price" class="form-control" type="number"
>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!--end modal body-->

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="save_product_format">
                     Save
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>  <!--end modal content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to read a property of a returned json object that contains an html string? What does the response look like If you trace what is coming back?

Comment: no, it just a html view, not as a json object.

Comment: Can you trace the incoming response from the server?

Comment: yah. look at my response above.

Comment: So what value does data contain on success? Is it empty, null or something? Next, I would look at what the server intended to send back in that GET.

Comment: in the success callback i am not getting anything. there is nothing printing in console.log but in the error callback i am getting my response. do not why?

Comment: sorry, i have solved my problem. my controller function is look like this

$html = view('cms.formats.create_modal', compact('format'));
return response()->json(['html' => (String) $html]);